# Filter Powerapps Gallery by Filters or Search Bar

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have a gallery that I want users to be able to filter by either 3 unique filters (when one is selected the other 2 are automatically set to false) or by a search box.

I have the following code within my 3 filter buttons, which works to filter the gallery

```
Button 1 - UpdateContext({FilterbyAA:!FilterbyAA; FilterbyBB:false; FilterbyCC:false})
Button 2 - UpdateContext({FilterbyBB:!FilterbyBB; FilterbyAA:false; FilterbyCC:false})
Button 3 - UpdateContext({FilterbyCC:!FilterbyCC; FilterbyAA:false; FilterbyBB:false})
```

In my gallery I have the following code

```
If(
  FilterbyAA=true;
    Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="AA"); 
  FilterbyBB=true;
    Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="BB");
  FilterbyCC=true;
    Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="CC");
  Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off")
)
```

Could someone please tell me how I change this to say that if anything is entered into the search box, it should clear the filters and search by the search box entry instead?

I've tried the below but it doesn't work (the search does but not the filters)

```
If(Connection.Connected;Filter(EVENTDETAILS; StartsWith(EVENTNAME; SearchBox.Text));
    If(
      FilterbyAA=true;
        Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="AA"); 
      FilterbyBB=true;
        Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="BB");
      FilterbyCC=true;
        Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="CC");
      Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off")
    )
```

Comment: Hi @Michelle, did you try solution given in my answer below? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
If(
    IsBlank(SearchBox.Text);    
    If(
        FilterbyAA=true;
        Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="AA"); 
        FilterbyBB=true;
        Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="BB");
        FilterbyCC=true;
        Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="CC");
        Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off")
    );
    Filter(EVENTDETAILS; StartsWith(EVENTNAME; SearchBox.Text))
)
```